# Purpose of using session_encode() and session_decode()

Tags: php, function, session

I just want to figure out why and when should we use these functions? Actually what is the usage of these fucntions?

Comment: You probably never need to use them. They encode/decode the data in the PHP's superglobal `$_SESSION` variable. If you use the default session handling mechanism, what you'll get is the contents of a file that relates to a particular session (usually found in `/tmp`). You *might* need these functions if you're trying to implement some sort of clustering so you need to share sessions between different computers. However, not only are there better ways to achieve that, you most likely won't end up on that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are written to and read from a file on disk, and therefore need to be serialised into a storable format. They use their own custom serialisation format for writing the session contents into the file. The `session_encode`/`session_decode` functions are the functions that are used to serialise and deserialise session data for writing into/reading from a file.

There's no reason why you'd really need to use these low level implementation details on a day to day basis. However, should you ever find yourself working on some low level plumbing code which needs to work with serialised sessions, these functions may come in handy.

Comment: I got what the session_encode() is . could you explain more about session_decode(), please? thanks

Comment: It's the opposite of `session_encode`...!? Does [the manual](http://php.net/session_decode) not explain it sufficiently?

Comment: Whenever I print `session_decode()` it retruns "1" . Do you know what that "1" is ?

Comment: Looks like you have not read [the manual](http://php.net/session_decode). `session_decode` *"returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure."* It does not *return* its decoded data, its return value is mostly meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

session is stored in the temporary folder on the server as a text files and you can access this files and read all the data...so it is also for security reasons

Comment: Also the session is stored in the temporary folder on the server as a text files and you can access this files and read all the data...so it is also for security reasons...